# not able to exclude fields from Meteor collection in Houston

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I'm using Houston for an Admin section to my Meteor app, but there are a lot of fields I don't need to see. I'm thinking I want to avoid publishing those fields from mongo in the first place, rather than eliminate them in a convoluted way in the template.

Here's the coffeescript in Houston in server/publications.coffee:

```
Houston._publish name, (sort, filter, limit, unknown_arg) ->
  check sort, Match.Optional(Object)
  check filter, Match.Optional(Object)
  check limit, Match.Optional(Number)
  check unknown_arg, Match.Any
  return unless Houston._user_is_admin @userId
  try
    collection.find(filter, sort: sort, limit: limit)
  catch e
    console.log e
```

Here's what I've tried to replace it with. This doesn't cause any errors, but it doesn't stop the fields from showing.

```
Houston._publish name, (sort, filter, limit, unknown_arg) ->
  check sort, Match.Optional(Object)
  check filter, Match.Optional(Object)
  check limit, Match.Optional(Number)
  check unknown_arg, Match.Any
  return  unless Houston._user_is_admin(@userId)
  try
    return collection.find(filter,
      sort: sort
      limit: limit
    ,
      fields:
        category: 0
        userId: 0
    )
  catch e
    console.log e
```

I'm not sure if my error is in my coffeescript conversion (I've double-checked indentation), or in my general approach.

Thanks for any help,

Charlie Magee